# How to draw route using lat long coordinates without reverse geocoding?

Tags: google-maps, geocoding

I would like to plot route between 2 points using lat long coordinates using Google maps direction service. I have to plot many routes in a single map. I have heard some where that it takes time for reverse geocoding and also there is a limit for it. Is it possible to do it without reverse geocoding the coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

If you already got the coordinates then you can just use [LeafLet](http://switch2osm.org/using-tiles/getting-started-with-leaflet/) or [OpenLayers](http://switch2osm.org/using-tiles/getting-started-with-openlayers/) to display them on a map. This doesn't involve Google Maps at all and you can also directy display a GPX file if you like to.